# sql server agent job with xp_cmdshell to move files

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have the following t-sql to move files from 1 directory to another.

I tried both versions.  job step succeeded with no errors, but files do not move.

any thoughts/suggestions?

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell  ' Move /Y "C:\SomeFiles\" "C:\SomeFiles\FileArchive\" ';
```

EXEC xp_cmdshell  ' Move C:\SomeFiles\ C:\SomeFiles\FileArchive\ ';

Comment: Did you try running your command manually, outside SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Its because C:\SomeFiles\FileArchive\ is a Sub-Directory of C:\SomeFiles.  Try running the command from a command prompt to test.

```
move /Y C:\SomeFiles\*.* C:\SomeFiles\FileArchive\
```

Will get you what you want.